# How to remove duplicates from the collection of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a lot of lists and need to create a collection of unique lists in python.

```
# Input
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [1, 4, 6]
l3 = [1, 2, 3]
# Output
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6]]
```

I tried to create a `set` of lists

```
set([l1, l2, l3])
```

, but got an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Is there any easy way to remove list duplicates from my collection?

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [1, 4, 6]
l3 = [1, 2, 3]

output = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6]]
```

**EDIT** solution from comments:

```
>>> set([tuple(x) for x in [l1, l2, l3]])
{(1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 6)}
>>> [list(x) for x in set([tuple(x) for x in [l1, l2, l3]])]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Provide example and expected output

Comment: Transform the list into a tuple and then do the set.

Comment: Make them into tuples and then add them.

Comment: You can not put lists into a `set`. Python simply does not allow it. Convert the lists to `tuple`, then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using itertools we can do this

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6]]
>>> list(lst for lst,_ in itertools.groupby(lst))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6]]
>>>
```